# XCode GDB syntax for cell.detailTextLabel.text?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsstring, gdb

I have a typical UITableView app that has some cells with some labels..

How do you display the contents of the following using GDB? I have tried this below and cannot figure out what the syntax should be.

EDIT: I want to be able to display the contents of variables when the debugger hits a breakpoint

```
(gdb) p (NSString*)cell.detailTextLabel.text
There is no member named detailTextLabel.
(gdb) p (NSString*)[cell.detailTextLabel.text]
A syntax error near end of expression.
(gdb) p (NSString*)[cell detailTextLabel text]
A syntax error in expression, near `]'.
(gdb) p (NSString*)[cell detailTextLabel]
$2 = (NSString *) 0x0
(gdb) p (NSString*)[[cell detailTextLabel] text]
$3 = (NSString *) 0x0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dot notation inside the debugger, so instead of `cell.detailTextLabel.text` you would have to write `[[cell detailTextLabel] text]`. And try using the command `po` instead of `p`, so `po [[cell detailTextLabel] text]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still not working for me: (gdb) po [[cell detailTextLabel] text]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
(gdb) po [[cell detailTextLabel] text]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
(gdb) po (NSString*)[[cell detailTextLabel] text]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
(gdb) po (NSString)[[cell detailTextLabel] text]
Value can't be converted to integer.

Comment: well then that means that at some point either your label or your cell is being released, meaning it's `nil` when you try to print out its contents. Try `po cell` to see if the cell is nil.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right - I recently changed the assignment of the labels to use copies of an NSString * so its looking as though that was the case. Interestingly enough, I'm also finding that I can use dot notation on C structures. Thanks for your help - I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but to log the text of a label you can use:

```
NSLog(@"%@",cell.detailTextLabel.text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - its actually the debugger that I'm wanting to use to view variables (gdb). What you have suggested will indeed log output to the debugger window but I want to examine different variables when I hit a break point. Sorry - I should have mentioned the fact that I'm using a breakpoint in my posting. Cheers.